# Error en crear archivo CVS en java

Tags: java

espero que me puedan ayudar, estoy en la clase de organizacion de archvios y estamos viendo como crear un archivo CVS en java.

Mi problema es que cuando compilo mi codigo y lo abro con excel no me respeta las comas, osea escribe todo junto en una sola casilla, en vez de escribir en casillas separadas. No se si sea el codigo o mi excel. yo tengo el office 2008 y como soy estudiante tengo la version para universidades. No se si eso sirva de algo.

En verdad espero que me puedan ayudar a resolver esto, ya que tengo que entregar una tarea parecida y pues si no puedo solucionar este error no podre entregar mi tarea.

Este es mi codigo:

```
File fichero = new File("C:\\Prueba/FicheroCVS.cvs");
    try {
        if (fichero.createNewFile()) {
            System.out.println("El archivo se ha creado correctamente");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Archivo no creado");
        }

        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(fichero);

        //ENCABEZADO DE MI TABLA
        writer.append("NoCta");
        writer.append(",");
        writer.append("Nombre");
        writer.append(",");
        writer.append("APaterno");
        writer.append(",");
        writer.append("AMaterno");
        writer.append(",");
        writer.append("Semestre");
        writer.append(",");
        writer.append("Licenciatura");
        writer.append(";");
        writer.append("Promedio");
        writer.append('\n');

        writer.append("9814635");
        writer.append(",");
        writer.append("JOSE JAIR");
        writer.append(",");
        writer.append("VAZQUEZ");
        writer.append(",");
        writer.append("PALMA");
        writer.append(",");
        writer.append("5");
        writer.append(",");
        writer.append("ICO");
        writer.append(",");
        writer.append("6.3");
        writer.append('\n');

        writer.append("9814636");
        writer.append(",");
        writer.append("JUAN JOSE");
        writer.append(",");
        writer.append("PEREZ");
        writer.append(",");
        writer.append("LEON");
        writer.append(",");
        writer.append("5");
        writer.append(",");
        writer.append("ICO");
        writer.append(",");
        writer.append("9.5");
        writer.append('\n');
        
        writer.append("123456");
        writer.append(",");
        writer.append("ALMA");
        writer.append(",");
        writer.append("VAZQUEZ");
        writer.append(",");
        writer.append("JIMENEZ");
        writer.append(",");
        writer.append("5");
        writer.append(",");
        writer.append("ICO");
        writer.append(",");
        writer.append("9.5");
        writer.append('\n');

        writer.flush();
        writer.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: ¡Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Mira [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu [primera medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Abre el archivo que se está creando y dinos si es correcto. Luego, al cargarlo en Excel tendrás que indicar cuál es el separador, si es la coma, o el punto y coma, o un tab, etc. Si la coma no es el separador por defecto y no lo indicas como separador no te creará bien las filas y celdas.

Comment: Parece ser un problema que contiene errores tipográficos. CVS significa sistema de control de versiones, mientras que la extensión que abre excel es CSV, Comma Separated Values.

Comment: Después de _Licenciatura_ tienes `writer.append(";");`, debería ser `,`

Answer (score 0):

Lo primero que te aconsejo es usar la librería **OpenCSV**, que te permite escribir un CSV de forma mucho mas cómoda (Para ello debes importarla).

Te voy a poner varios ejemplos y varias explicaciones que he sacado de  [**este enlace.**](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/writing-a-csv-file-in-java-using-opencsv)

- #### Ejemplo 1:

En este ejemplo vamos a ver la funcionalidad mas básica posible, vamos a hacer unas columnas e introducirlas en un archivo, fila a fila.

```java
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;

import com.opencsv.CSVWriter;

public class Pruebas {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        File file = new File("./archivo.csv");
        
        try {
            FileWriter outputFile = new FileWriter(file);
            CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(outputFile);
            
            // Declaramos las filas.
            String[] cabecera = { "Nombre", "Apellidos", "Edad", "Sexo" };
            String[] fila1 = {"Ruben", "Garcia Lozano", "24", "Hombre" }; 
            String[] fila2 = {"Maria", "Montero Vera", "15", "Mujer" }; 
            
            // Ahora las vamos a insertar
            
            writer.writeNext(cabecera);
            writer.writeNext(fila1);
            writer.writeNext(fila2);
            
            //Cerramos todo
            writer.close();
            outputFile.close();
        } catch (IOException exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

- #### Ejemplo2

En este ejemplo vamos a insertar varias filas a la vez. Para ello vamos a usar una colección y vamos a meter el conjunto de Strings en la colección:

```java
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import com.opencsv.CSVWriter;

public class Pruebas {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        File file = new File("./archivo.csv");
        
        try {
            FileWriter outputFile = new FileWriter(file);
            CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(outputFile);
            
            List<String[]> filas = new ArrayList();
            
            // Declaramos las filas.
            String[] cabecera = { "Nombre", "Apellidos", "Edad", "Sexo" };
            String[] fila2 = {"Maria", "Montero Vera", "15", "Mujer" }; 
            
            // Las metemos en la coleccion (de varias maneras distintas.
            filas.add(new String[] {"Ruben", "Garcia Lozano", "24", "Hombre"});
            filas.add(fila2);
            // Ahora las vamos a insertar
            
            writer.writeNext(cabecera);
            
            // Con esta instruccion escribimos todo
            writer.writeAll(filas);
            
            //Cerramos todo
            writer.close();
            outputFile.close();
        } catch (IOException exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Puedes encontrar muchísima mas información en el enlace que te deje arriba. Espero que te haya servido de ayuda y te haya aclarado las dudas.

Un saludo.